# Passing bool to a child component doesn't work correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to have my user optionally have a textbox get a default value or not. Fill-in form to record how many of an item delivered. Can be blank, or can auto-calc how many of an item should arrive based on quantity ordered minus quantity already received. I can do the math!

I have a boolean set with React Hooks which toggles when you click a link. I hoped that this would cause a re-render of line items with the textbox either populated or not, depending on passing 'AutoFill' in the props collection. Seems simple enough. Works like a dream if I hard-code true or false into that property. Fails completely if I insert the variable instead.
I'm a bit new to React but I thought I was capable of this. Likely missing something obvious or failing to comprehend correctly lifecycle and the rendering process.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  const [af, setAf] = useState(false);

  const theList = [
    { Id: 1, Quantity: 7, Received: 4 },
    { Id: 2, Quantity: 4, Received: 0 }
  ];

  const setVal = (id, val) => {
    console.log(`Value for Id ${id} was set by child to ${val}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setAf(!af)}>Toggle</div>
      {theList.map((itm, idx) => {
        return (
          <LineItem onChange={setVal} key={idx} AutoFill={af} Data={itm} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function LineItem(props) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(
    props.AutoFill ? props.Data.Quantity - props.Data.Received : undefined
  );

  const setValue = newVal => {
    setVal(newVal);
    props.onChange(props.Data.Id, newVal);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>Value: {val}</p>
      <p>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={val}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

App component should show a list of  components. Passes in a bool to decide whether to do the sum and populate the textbox or not.

If I go with hardcoding the value of the AutoFill property it works every time with the right maths, or blank as I'd want. When I put the variable in, it's always blank - it never pre-populates the textbox in the  component.

Comment: You said `When I put the variable in, it's always blank`. What do you mean? Can you show an example of which value you pass to `af`?

Comment: Why do you use functional components when they are not stateless?

Comment: @NicoDiz This line: <LineItem onChange={setVal} key={idx} AutoFill={af} Data={itm} /> if AutoFill={af} it never works. If I hard code it to AutoFill={true} or AutoFill={false} it behaves as I would want.

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to `useState` is used only once and so when you change the value of `AutoFill` prop, the state isn't evaluated again. To do that, you need to make use of `useEffect` hook

```
const [val, setVal] = useState(
    props.AutoFill ? props.Data.Quantity - props.Data.Received : undefined
  );


  useEffect(() => {
     if(props.AutoFill) {
        setVal(props.Data.Quantity - props.Data.Received)
     }
  }, [props.AutoFill, props.Data.Quantity, props.Data.Received]);
```

Working demo

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
function App() {

  const [af, setAf] = useState(false);

  const theList = [
    { Id: 1, Quantity: 7, Received: 4 },
    { Id: 2, Quantity: 4, Received: 0 }
  ];

  const setVal = (id, val) => {
    console.log(`Value for Id ${id} was set by child to ${val}`);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setAf(!af)}>Toggle</div>
      {theList.map((itm, idx) => {
        return (
          <LineItem onChange={setVal} key={idx} AutoFill={af} Data={itm} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function LineItem(props) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(
    props.AutoFill ? props.Data.Quantity - props.Data.Received : undefined
  );

  const setValue = newVal => {
    setVal(newVal);
    props.onChange(props.Data.Id, newVal);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
     if(props.AutoFill) {
        setVal(props.Data.Quantity - props.Data.Received)
     }
  }, [props.AutoFill, props.Data.Quantity, props.Data.Received]);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Value: {val}</p>
      <p>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={val}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: This is fine but then I can never change the value in the text box?

Comment: @MichaelC Added a working demo, also please note that since the input is of type number, you can't type text in there